# SQL Server Database Error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' ' to data type int

Tags: sql, toad

I am running this in TOAD. Please forgive my ignorance, I am new to SQL.

```
Select * from Database where [Encounter Number] in ( 12345678910, 10987654321, 11121314151)
```

it ran once and gave me all of the data I was looking for but now when I execute this query, I keep getting Database Error 'SQL Server Database Error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '    ' to data type int. '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `[Encounter Number]` is a string, so the comparison value should be strings:

```
[Encounter Number] in ('12345678910', '10987654321', '11121314151')
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped.